# How to use this PhoneGap Snippet?

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

ive a very simple basic question.
I just want to know, how im using this code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
// set splash screen
super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splash);
super.init();
// clear cache
super.clearCache();
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");}
```

I thought in phonegap i can use only javascript/html/css ?
But this is Java or not?
I have this from here [coderwall](https://coderwall.com/p/aj79eg/adding-a-splash-screen-and-clearing-cache-with-phonegap-and-android)
I just want to clear the cache from my App!

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap creates a "wrapper" where it starts a webserver (I think it is a webserver) and a WebView. Then, are files served by this webserver, will be showed in the WebView (CSS, HTML, Javascript and resources like images).

All wrapper, Activity creation and everything else is Java code. When you generates your Android app (not APK, the code of the app!) you can modify this code (wich is written in Java) and has the same structure as a normal Android app (and a folder where there are your HTML/CSS...).

So, when you generates app code, you can modify MainActivity.java and add the code that you read in this web.

I hope my answer will be helpful for you!

Comment: Ah! Ok, but im using the build.phonegap website and there is no MainActivity.java in my PhoneGap folder. So must i use the phonegap CLI ?

Comment: Yes. You should.
I remind you to use Cordova (it is the same but it is free software -open source-)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to modify Cordova's auto-generated Java files. In this case, the file you're looking for depends on the id of your app - if you're not sure, check your config.xml.

If your app id was com.example.app, then the location of the file you want to edit is **platforms/android/src/com/example/app/MainActivity.java**.